# How to determine if the current window is the active window?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, mfc

How can I tell if my window is the current active window?
My current guess is to do GetForegroundWindow and compare the HWND with that of my window.
Is there a better method than that?

I'm using Win32 API / MFC.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, that's the only way that I'm aware of.

But you have to handle the fact that GFW can return NULL. Typically, this happens when another desktop (e.g. the screen saver desktop) is active. Note that use of a saver password can affect whether a different desktop is used (this is windows version-dependent and I can't remember the details of how different versions work).

Also this code won't work properly in debug mode under Visual Studio, because you will get VS's window handle.

Other than that everything's peachy :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can try to use WM_ACTIVATEAPP message.
First define a bool variable `bool wActive = false`, in the WndProc procedure, here is the next piece of code:

```
case WM_ACTIVATEAPP:
     wActive = (bool)wParam;
return 0;
```

You can go to [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-activateapp?redirectedfrom=MSDN) to find more information about `WM_ACTIVATEAPP`

Comment: I have been not developing with MSDN stuff for years, so this answer maybe invalid.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are correct unless otherwise you want to check activewindow of every thread.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you mean the window which has the input focus when you say "active window"?

In that case, forget the GetForegroundWindow() API. That will return the topmost window - not always the window which has the input focus.

Use [GetFocus()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646294(VS.85).aspx) instead.

Comment: That is false: "GetFocus returns the window with the keyboard focus for the current thread's message queue. [...] Use the GetForegroundWindow function to retrieve the handle to the window with which the user is currently working."

Comment: As I said: "if you mean the window which has the input focus".

Comment: GetFocus only works "for the current thread's message queue", that's what I meant. GetForegroundWindow is the API to call, and the name is misleading. That window may not be the topmost in the z-order, but it returns the window which has the global focus. i.e. "is active".

Answer (score 0):

Yea, GetForgroundWindow() is a good way to check, behaves correctly even with a "Always on top" window aka HWND_TOPMOST .

Another way is with GetActiveWindow()

```
    HWND temp = GetActiveWindow();
    if (temp == hWnd) // Then your current window has focus
```

Alternatively the following messages report if the focus has changed

```
    case WM_KILLFOCUS:
        // windowHasFocus = false
    break;

    case WM_SETFOCUS:
        // windowHasFocus = true;
    break;
```