# What's the 'opposite' of OnSetActive()?

Tags: c++, mfc, timer

i have a bunch of PropertyPages stucked together with a PropertyPage (to create a tabbed view).
one of these pages starts a timer inside of its OnSetActive() method to refresh some status information.
now i want this timer to stop if i leave this tab and change my view. which event is fired after 'leaving' a tab?
i've tried OnKillActive(), OnClose(), OnKillFocus() but neither of them work as expected. any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

alright, we've found a working solution

```
void Status::OnShowWindow(BOOL bShow, UINT nStatus) {
    if (bShow == 0) {
        selectedDevice= NULL;   
        KillTimer(TIMER_ID);            }
    CMFCPropertyPage::OnShowWindow(bShow, nStatus);
}
```

`OnShowWindow()` is called either at entering and leaving the page, 
´bShow` is the actual status (true when entering, false when leaving)

`OnShowWindow()` is declarated as afx_msg and triggered by an `ON_WM_SHOWWINDOW` event

thanks for all your help

Answer (score 4):

According to the documentation, OnKillActive should be exactly what you're looking for. If you put a breakpoint in the function do you hit it?

Generally when you leave a tab, the tab is still alive and waiting in the background. You could continue to wait for the timer message and just ignore it if you're not the active tab.

Edit: you say in the comments that OnKillActive is not being called. One of the nice things about MFC is that Microsoft gives you the source code to browse; the call to OnKillActive is generated in CPropertyPage::OnNotify. There are a couple of conditions that would cause it to return early before reaching that point. One is a call to CDialog::OnNotify, which has the suspicious comment "allow message map to override". This implies that if you have your own OnNotify handler for WM_NOTIFY, and it returns TRUE, the default processing will be skipped.

Comment: that's what i thought after reading the documentation, unfortunatley the brekapoint isn't hit. you mean, i should use this solution to get the active window: [](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/510845/how-to-determine-if-the-current-window-is-the-active-window)

Comment: No, I meant CPropertySheet::GetActivePage. Also see my update.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply have a timer that fires periodically as you already have and within the timer callback get the current active tab and refresh if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The function you're looking for is `virtual BOOL OnKillActive()`
It's called on the tab you're leaving before activating another page
Here, at work, we use it to validate if the user can change the page and prevent the page change by returning false.

If the event isn't fired, maybe you can look in your header file if your marked your `OnKillActive` as virtual. If you didn't, the event will not fire.

Comment: according to the documentations it should do so. OnKillActive() is virtual, yes. but me breakpoint doesn't hit