# Process IsFocused .net C++ or C#

Tags: c#, c++, focus

How to check in Process object is Focused? Please reply with c++ od c# code
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should explain how can a process be "focused"

Comment: If is on top of screen... I don't know how can i explain it more...

Comment: GetForegroundWindow ... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633505(v=vs.85).aspx ... also read this on difference between active and focus.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to determine if the current window is the active window?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/510845/how-to-determine-if-the-current-window-is-the-active-window)

Comment: "If is on top of screen" as topmost window - `SetWindowPos(...HWND_TOPMOST...)` - (may not have focus at all)?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code based on GetForegroundWindow()

```
var process = GetForegroundWindow();
if (process != IntPtr.Zero) {
    return true;       // he has focus
}
```

Comment: I don't want to set this window focused... I want just check is it Focused.. that's all