# Bypass trigger of OnFocus/GetFocus event if the application window loses activation c++

Tags: c++, mfc, cedit

I have a text box which take string value. On Focus lost it does a specific function (say function 1). But even if I lost focus on the window, this OnFocus event is getting triggered.

Suppose i have the following code :

```
classA::OnTextBoxFocus()
{
   CWnd* pCurrentFocus = GetFocus();

  // if focus event execute function 1

}
```

Now I want to put a check, to find out if the application window is active. Only if the Window is active, `OnFocus` event should get triggered.

I learned that using GetActiveWindow() or GetForegroundWindow() through the post  "[determine if the current window is the active window?(StackOverflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510845/how-to-determine-if-the-current-window-is-the-active-window)"

However I am finding difficult it putting this check. Can you help me in understanding, how to implement, through an example?

Comment: referred this link(  http://stackoverflow.com/a/511350/3341400 ) to learn to use GetActiveWindow() or GetForegroundWindow()

Comment: [WM_KILLFOCUS is the wrong time to do field validation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/04/19/115912.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried checking if the On focus event is NULL.

```
classA::OnTextBoxFocus()
{
   CWnd* pCurrentFocus = GetFocus();

  if(pCurrentFocus != NULL)
  // if focus event execute function 1

}
```

this is currently working as expected. Now I can bypass OnFocus event if change the current window.

Comment: Is there any other way of doing this?